# Example of function with open and bounded image

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm trying to understand the intuition behind continuity and boundedness.
Can someone give me an example of a continuous function f:$\mathbb{R}^2$ →$\mathbb{R}$ whose image is bounded and open?

Would $f(x, y) := $ ${\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}$ be one? I know this function is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Take of for instance

$$g(x,y)=\arctan(x).$$

Then the image would be $\arctan(\mathbb R)=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ which is bounded and open.

The function

$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}$$

that you gave is not working because take for instance

$$f(n,0)=\sqrt{n^2}=\vert n\vert\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}+\infty$$

so the image is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Take $g:\mathbb{R} \to (-1,1)$ given by $g(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$. This is continuous and surjective.

Consider now $\pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ the projection on the first coordinate.

$f:=g \circ \pi$ satisfies what you want.